# Can't get php file to insert into database using ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm quite new to ajax and php. I've been trying to insert the text found in my dynamically generated js table into the database, but I just can't get it to work.

My main issue is that I have got it to work on a different table in the database, from a different page of the site.

```
<button id="saveScorecard">Save Scorecard</button>
```

The above triggers the below js event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("document loaded");
    $('#saveScorecard').click(function() {
        //Get value of item name
        var place_1 = $("#scorecard table tbody #tr0 td:first-child").html();
        console.log($("#scorecard table tbody #tr0 td:first-child").html());
        var place_2 = $("#scorecard table tbody #tr1 td:first-child").html();
        var place_3 = $("#scorecard table tbody #tr2 td:first-child").html();;
        var user_id = 1;
        
        $('#saveScorecard').prop("disabled", true);

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/upload.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {place1 : place_1, 
                   place2 : place_2, 
                   place3 : place_3, 
                   userid : 1}
            
        });
        console.log("sent data to php file");

        request.always(function () {
            $('#saveScorecard').prop("disabled", false);
        });

    });
    
});
```

**upload.php:**

```
<?php

require_once('../includes/db.php');


if($_POST['place_1_name'] && $_POST['place_2_name'] && $_POST['place_3_name']){


   $query = "INSERT INTO scorecards (place_1_name, place_2_name, place_3_name, user_id) 
   
   VALUES 
   (:place_1, :place_2, :place_3, :user_id)";
   
   $result = $DBH->prepare($query);
   $result->bindParam(':place_1', $_POST['place1']);
   $result->bindParam(':place_2', $_POST['place2']);
   $result->bindParam(':place_3', $_POST['place3']);
   $result->bindParam(':user_id', $_POST['userid']);

   $result->execute();
   echo $DBH->lastInsertId();
}

?>
```

**The site is hosted through plesk if that helps.**

Please ignore the clutter and indivdual definition of all of the table cells, I've been focused on trying to get it to work before tidying it up.

Also any tips on php debugging would be great, as sometimes the errors arent logged in the console or error logs.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `if($_POST['place_1_name']` -- you're not sending `place_1_name` from javascript, but `place1` (same for `place2` and `place3`)

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that I had altered that at the end, I think during my testing I went from one problem to another until it was just the wrong variable name, definately facepalming right now. (I'm really bad with this site but I think you need to submit it as an answer for me to accept it?)

Comment: Think you can delete the question in this case, as it was a typo not a coding issue.

Comment: @user3783243 What about their valuable time which they have used to write down a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @MUFAzmi They got the answer so their time hasn't been wasted. This question is of no use to future visitors. It is one of the close reason's on the site and has been discussed in the past, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo. Additionally, if someone else wrote an answer please don't take their credit. If you feel it should have an answer have the contributing user post it.

Comment: A question without an answer may be deleted automatically.

Comment: That's why I have wrote an answer.. that's it

Comment: The reason I posted my "answer" as a comment was to help OP out quickly. But I still voted to close this as a typo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**TYPOGRAPHICAL ERROR**

> You are condition is checking the data which you have never send it.

In your upload.php file you are checking the condition...

```
if($_POST['place_1_name'] && $_POST['place_2_name'] && $_POST['place_3_name'])
{
    //your codes
}
```

but you are sending the data using ajax is...

```
data: { place1 : place_1, 
        place2 : place_2, 
        place3 : place_3, 
        userid : 1}
```

> Either you have to change the key from JQuery or PHP to solve the
> problem.

Once you changed the keys to what you are sending, Your problem will be solved

for example:

```
if($_POST['place1'] && $_POST['place2'] && $_POST['place3'])
{
    //your codes
}
```